# Issue in url handlers of google endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am having the url handler as below in my app.yaml

```
handlers:

- url: /_ah/spi/websiteapi/.*
  script: Website.application
  secure: always
```

But while accessiong the api using http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/websiteapi/v1/websites  i am getting error as 
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "BackendService.getApiConfigs Error"
      }
    }

```
Help me to configure mt url handler and the below setting works fine but i need to handle several scripts depending on the url. 
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: Website.application
  secure: always
```

Answer (score 0):

Requests to `/_ah/spi` on App Engine need to be handled by a Google Cloud Endpoints server in order to serve the correct responses.

Your script `Website.application` should be an `endpoints.api_server` object. Here's a working example:

In `app.yaml`

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: main.endpoints_app
```

In `main.py`:

```
import endpoints
import services  # Your Cloud Endpoints handlers go here.

endpoints_app = endpoints.api_server([
    services.MyService1,
    services.MyService2
])
```

Full docs are here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api#coding_a_backend_with_a_simple_get_method

Comment: It works fine thanks a lot for the answer, but is there any way we can mention for this pattern of url go to this script in url handlers in app.yaml.